# Hosting asp.net core on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ubuntu-14.04, asp.net-core

I have a problem with hosting my web app. I am using DigitalOcean ubuntu 14.04 as my server and I am following this http://blog.jsinh.in/hosting-asp-net-5-web-application-on-linux/#.VxNtBPmLSUl tutorial. The problem I get is that I don't know how to "put" my project to the server. I already published it using dnu and including dnx-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1 . I have it on my github https://github.com/ziombo/KISDNU but I still dont know how to deploy it to my linux server and what to do next.

Comment: This is a server related question!

Comment: Oh, right I apologize. Server Faul is the place for these questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see :

- Official doc: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html
- Digital Ocean related walkthrough: https://blog.theobjectifiedprogrammer.com/install-vnext-on-digitalocean-ubuntu-droplet/